# C++ lib for FTP upload over FTP proxy

Tags: c++, proxy, ftp

I'm trying to write a C++ component to upload a file on a FTP server through a FTP proxy (specified by host/port/user/password).

In a first time I tried using Qt (QNetworkAccessManager/QNetworkProxy) but for an unknown reason it does not work (when I try to upload the same file with FileZilla using the same connection parameters, it works). My code also works when I have no proxy.
In a second time, I tried with libcurl but it seems this lib does not support FTP proxy.
Any suggestion of another C++ lib I could try? or a Win32 (winsock) example?

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting Windows, you can try using the [Windows Internet APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to implement the FTP client. I'd imagine you'll have an easier time using them rather than manually implement an FTP client atop sockets.

I haven't looked at them, but there seem to be [a few samples here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289253).